# Запрос к БД из PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос из PHP к mysql:

```
$str = "SELECT id*2 FROM `solution` WHERE 1";
$res =  mysql_query($str);
```

Вопрос такой, как обратиться к полю id*2 ?

Я пробовал mysql_result($res,0,'id*2'); но он не выдает результат. Пожалуйста, помогите с этим разобраться.Эту задачу легко решить сделав запрос на поле id а потом его в php просто умножить на 2, но мне нужен ответ именно на тот вопрос, который я задал без всяких обходных путей. Просто, проблему которую я встретил не решить таким обходным путем, а нужно именно в лоб.

Comment: А что значит `WHERE 1` ?

Comment: Это значит, что условие всегда верно, -> выдаст все записи из таблицы.

Comment: а без условия он выдаст не все?

Comment: @rasmisha, ну хочется человеку, это ж не ошибка ;) И никто не говорил, что избыточный код - это смертельно ))

Comment: меня как джависта конечно убивает неявное приведение инта (и не только его) к boolean

Comment: неявное приведение инта в булеан это вполне нормально, я всегда этим пользуюсь, потери значения никогда не произойдет.

Comment: я ничего против Вас не говорю. Но мне просто такое трудно читать в чужом коде (благо редко такие ситуации вообще бывают)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, раз надо, то делайте так:

```
$str =  "SELECT (`id` * 2) AS total FROM `solution` WHERE 1";
$res =  mysql_query($str);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    echo $row['total'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: В данном случае, выведет все строки. А можно не выводить все, а обратиться к определенной (например к 3). У меня туго с ассоциативными массивами...

Comment: А кто сказал, что обязательно именно так? Делайте **mysql_fetch_array()** или вообще **mysql_fetch_row()** для получения массива с числовыми индексами и би хэппи ;)

Comment: Это то, что нужно, спасибо.